# I'm new in Ubuntu and want to know about support lifespan

Tags: 15.10

I'm new in Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 15.10. In support lifespan ( in this link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes?_ga=1.241738310.574068313.1451850568 ) it is mentioned that, "Ubuntu 15.10 will be supported for 9 months". So, What to do after 9 months? will my OS become useless after 9 months?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your system will remain usable after 9 months, of course, but it will no longer receive bug fixes and security updates, which could leave it vulnerable to security attacks. You should upgrade to 16.04 when it is released, or soon afterwards.

Comment: How can I upgrade to 16.04 when it will be available?

Comment: It will be explained in the release notes for 16.04. (Note that the release notes for 15.10 that you have linked explain how to upgrade from 15.04.)